# Show div for a moment then switch to another div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an animation with `jQuery 1.9.1` where I want to show a div for a short moment then switch it with the defualt div at button click. So far I've tried using `show()` & `hide()` method. But nothing is working. Here are my codes,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#btnChange').click(function () {
            $('#red').hide();
            $('#blue').show().delay(1500).hide();
            $('#red').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f87zp3rg/2/)

How can I show a div for a moment and after that switch it with the default div `#red` at button click? Neec this help badly. Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tza15dms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set duration for [.hide( [duration ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method, it'll be placed in `fx queue` and so delay would work:

> You should `stop()` any previous animation to better handling multiple
>   clicks btw

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#btnChange').click(function () {
        $('#red').hide();
        $('#blue')/*.stop()*/.show().delay(1500).hide(0);
        $('#red').show();
    });
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

With `.stop()`:

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Thanks. This looks much promising. Actually in my real program, I'm using images in the divs. So I see my default div `#red` also when the switching happens. Any reason u know why it's happening?

Comment: @SinOscuras Please consider updating jsFiddle replicating your issue. Here it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/f87zp3rg/7/

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. My div size wasn't exact same. It's fine now. Thanks a lot for this tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#btnChange').click(function () {
    $('#red').hide();
    $('#blue').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#blue').hide();
      $('#red').show();
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
#red{
    position: absolute;
 width: 178px;
 height: 124px;
    background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#blue{
    position: absolute;
 width: 178px;
 height: 124px;
    background-color: blue;
 overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
#btnChange{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<button id="btnChange">Change!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#blue').show('slow', function(){
        $('#blue').hide();              
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f87zp3rg/3/

Answer (score 0):

You showing your `#red` again to fast.. use `setTimeout`

> window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#btnChange').click(function () {
        $('#red').hide();
        $('#blue').show();
        window.setTimeout(function() { 
          $('#red').show(); 
          $('#blue').hide()
        },1500);
    });
});
```

**JSFidde:**
http://jsfiddle.net/f87zp3rg/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#btnChange').click(function () {

    $('#red').fadeOut(500);
    $('#blue').fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('#blue').delay(3000).hide();
        $('#red').delay(5000).show();
    });
  });
});
```